# google-charts-node server on node js with ubuntu

Tags: node.js, charts

nodes-noobie question...

I have succesfully worked with google charts on the client side.
Now I am trying to create my own google-charts server with node.js and google-charts-node to serve charts as image files to my PHP server.

I succesfully installed nodejs and Google Charts Node.

I can run a simple web server from this nodejs.

However, I get stuck trying to create a chart... As per a previous question on the subject, I created a file.js with the following code:

```
const GoogleChartsNode = require('google-charts-node');

// Define your chart drawing function
function drawChart() {
  const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population'],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000],
  ]);

  const options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: { width: '50%' },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0,
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City',
    },
  };

  const chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Render the chart to image
const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart);
```

When I run `node file.js` I get

```
const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart);
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I realize I am completely lost... Any help would be most appreciated.

Just to clarify, my goal is to have a server that can create google chart images and serve them via curl to my program servers, much like the hosted version of quickchart.io.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the javascript code was flawed...

However, this code from the examples folder does work:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const GoogleChartsNode = require('../index');

(async () => {
  const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(myChart, {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
  });

  fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/google-chart.png', image);
})();

function myChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population'],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: { width: '50%' },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0,
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City',
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
```